# pymysql incorrect writes to the database the Russian text

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, urllib, pymysql

I had the following problem: is There a site encoded in windows-1251. I'm using the library BeautifulSoup to get the data you need in Russian language. For testing recorded the values in the file, they are displayed correctly. Then I tried to record this data to the database, but got this error: `Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\x98\\xD0\\xBD\\xD1\\x82\\xD0...' for column 'description' at row 1")`
The database encoding is utf-8.
Below code demonstrates how to read html file:

```
def get_html(url):
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
return response.read()
```

The code below demonstrates how to write values to the database:

```
def write_to_db(chars, desc):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
        port=3307, 
        user='****',
        password='****',
        db='****',
        charset='utf8', 
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

global _id
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`id_cat`, `characteristics`, `description`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (_id, chars, desc))
conn.commit()
```

In the end we get in the database the following characters:`РњРѕРґРµР»СЊ`

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to change the encoding of the whole html file to utf8, I got an error that some characters can not be decoded. And in the way presented below, we have already received the Russian text without unnecessary symbols and can calmly decode it

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO `articles` (`id_cat`, `characteristics`, `description`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (_id, chars.encode('utf8'), desc.encode('utf8')))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: an explanation as to why that would do the trick helps everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the database encoding to cp1251_general_ci.

On [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html) you can check the Cyrillic Character Sets and collations.